# sharedPreferenceActivity auto closed when firebase value changes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am having a shared preference activity in which user can change some data about them and that trigers the change on firebase database

what i dont understand is that when ever a value is changed the preference activity finishes

my code goes as follows

```
public class PatientPersonalInformation extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

private LoadingDialog dialog;
private FirebaseUserGrabber userGrabber;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.patientpersonal);
    userGrabber = new FirebaseUserGrabber(this);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
    switch (s) {
        case "emergencynumber":
            userGrabber.setEmergencyNumber(sharedPreferences.getString(s, ""));
            break;
        case "useCoupons":
            userGrabber.setCopounsUsage(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(s, false), false);
            break;
    }
}
```

}

userGrabber is just that code

```
ref.child(path).setValue(data).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            //just toast
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            //just Toast
        }
    });;
```

and according to debugging if this line was succeeded it causes the activity to close ,otherwise nothing happens

**edit 1**

what i figured out is that the activity itself doesn't get closed,it's just the other activity get opened(no code written for that) and the preference activity is hidden in the back,looks like firebase listener is trigered and activate its activity(i am using listenerForSingleValueEvent())+ i tried to change fields with no listeners attached to it at all and the same happens too

can anyone explain,thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're seeing when you say "according to debugging"?  Are you seeing something in logcat?

Comment: no its just after reaching that specific line it closes the activity

Comment: Can you attach logcat log messages around the time this happens, with a mark in there at the time of the close, to the best of your ability to estimate that?  This doesn't seem possible to diagnose without lots more information.

Comment: what i figured out is that the activity itself doesn't get closed,it's just the other activity get opened(no code written for that) and the preference activity is hidden in the back,looks like firebase listener is trigered and activate its activity(i am using listenerForSingleValueEvent())+i tried to change fields with no listeners attached to it at all and the same happens too

Comment: Listeners won't start or finish activities unless you code them to do so.

Comment: well that's why i am asking .i worked with both firebase and preference activites many times so i can setup them correctly + the whole code is all up there